# Dynamic/Onspot JTextfield to JLabel

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jlabel, jtextfield

I want to make a pair JTextField/JLabel work as here on StackOverflow, I mean that I want a string to be displayed in JLabel as I write it in JTextField.

I tried adding ActionListener to JTextField but it works only for ENTER. Any ideas?

Comment: @calderon: please delete your comment as it is most definitely the wrong approach (as mKorbel has already pointed out. Much better to use a DocumentListener as Joe (1+) suggests as this will capture copy-pastes as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DocumentListener should allow you receive updates from a changing text field. I think you just need to override the changeUpdate method. Good luck!

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html

Comment: +1, Never tried this but it seems better then my recommendation above.